# eTa (electronic travel authorization) for Canada denied or approved?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, eta

I hope somebody who really knows about Canadian eTa permit can answer my question.

I was a university student in Canada for one year (2015 - 2016) and I had a valid student permit (which expired on the 30th of December 2016). I really want to go to Canada to visit my friends and I have never been denied a Canadian visa nor did I get denied my student permit/visa the first time that I applied for it.

I applied for U.S visa when I was in Vancouver and they denied it (as usual, since I am a Mexican citizen). I never had any trouble with Canadian authorities, but I got my U.S visa denied in Canada.

I'd like to travel to Canada to visit my friends and since my student visa/permit expired, I have to apply for a eTa as Mexico is part of the visa-exempt countries. There's a question on the eTa which says the following: "Have you ever been refused a visa or permit, denied entry or ordered to leave Canada or any other country?"

I know that I have to answer "Yes" and explain why. There's also another question which asks if you have ever had any kind of Canadian permit/visa which I've had (my Canadian study permit/visa).

Does it have a big impact if you've been denied a U.S visa? and would it be positive if I've had a Canadian study permit/visa before?

*I don't have any criminal record or overstayed in Canada. I actually left the country on September the 12th 2016 and my student visa expired on December the 31st 2016.

I am scared that I might get my eTa denied because of the declined U.S visa, which was total misunderstanding. When I arrived to the U.S consulate in Vancouver, the Chinese-American visa officer (who was really rude and impolite) asked me where did I want to go and I said: "to Seattle for a few days" and then he asked if I had any family in the U.S and I said: "No" cause I don't have any family in the U.S. He then told me that my application had been refused and when I asked about the reason he told me that I had lied. It's really unfair that because of him, I don't know what to explain on the eTa application and I know that the U.S and Canada share records. I feel really frustrated that it may affect my application.

Could somebody please help me out and guide me a little?

Comment: I suspect that the US visa denial will have a modest negative effect on your application and that your history of complying with your previous visa will have a much more significant positive impact.  But who knows, really?  The best thing to do is to apply.

Comment: Your U.S Visa refusal was under which section?

Comment: I am not familiar with sections but I remember that the officer gave me a blue paper which DIDN'T say anything specifically like "I was banned from the country because I had "lied" or something like that, it only said: your application has been refused and a list of reasons for why it could've been denied but nothing specifically. I don't have the paper anymore but I remember that I didn't say anything bad or unusual. Just a few reasons, that my application had been refused and some Q&A related to denial on the back of it. He didn't stamp or write anything on my passport either, is that good?

Comment: If it was just 214(b) it will have negligible impact but if it did say something about deception it might have a big impact but everything we say is guesswork. You won't find out until you apply

Comment: But if the paper didn't contain any specific information other than typical reasons and that my application had been denied, I guess it should be 214 (b), right? If it had been another one, it would've said something else. What do you think?

Comment: We are unable to predict whether or not your visa will be denied. Unfortunately the only way to find out is to go ahead and apply.